# Which gem to use: emberjs-rails vs rasputin vs ember-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js

I want to use ember.js in an application. Found that there are 3 gems for that:

1. emberjs-rails
2. rasputin
3. ember-rails

Not clear which one to go with. Please help me decide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend going with ember-rails, the officially maintained gem. Paul Chavard, the author of rasputin, has recently brought a lot of the [good ideas from rasputin](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/commits/master) into ember-rails.

Ember-rails pre-compiles handlebars templates and work with multiple extensions (".js.hjs", ".hbs" or ".handlebars"). It's also flexible in how templates are referenced from within your ember views (see the options in the README).

Unfortunately, I think there's been a temporary issue pushing updates to the gem to rubygems.org. For now, if you want to work with the latest rev, you'll need to include the gem straight from git:

```
gem 'ember-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails.git'
```